# What are the differences between the Decorator and Adapter patterns?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Under what conditions would it be better to use either the Adapter or the Decorator pattern?

Examples from real programs are welcome.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think these can be used interchangeably.

Adapter changes the interface of an object to adapt it to another interface. Decorator maintains the interface while adding features.

```
public class Foo
{
}

public class Bar
{
}

// adapter takes Foo and pretends it is Bar
public class FooBarAdapter : Bar
{
   public FooBarAdapter( Foo foo )
   {
   }
}

// decorator maintains the interface and adds features
public class FooDecorator : Foo
{
    public FooDecorator( Foo foo )
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm.. I thought that these patterns can be used interchangeably. Thanks for your sample!

Comment: Someone has misguided you. Adapter and Decorator are not related and I barely could think of a scenario where these two could be applied one vs the other.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I think the problem is that both of these patterns use composition to encapsulate a member object, which is why people might think they are similar. The key point here is, of course, the interface that is being exposed using that object.

Answer (score 5):

you have these links with uml diagram code and explain

adapter : http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx

=> Match interfaces of different classes

decorator :  http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx

=> Add responsibilities to objects dynamically

Comment: I was there. thanks!:) Could you tell me, please, where is better to use adapter and where another pattern? (i mean in "real life")

Comment: happy to help you, if you want communicate two systems use adapter in order to adapt communication, but decorator in order to add functinnalities to your object